# Extract the metadata from a Tif image in python where the separators are not all the same?

Tags: python, image, metadata, tiff

I have been searching for quite some time a solution to this problem.  I want read out the metadata from a TIF image from a microscope but the separators are not all the same between tags and values. Sometimes the separators are a semicolon(:) and sometimes equal signs(=).  I just want to extract it out to use a few lines of it.  Maybe someone has done this already?

Comment: if you can get it as single string then you can write own code to split on `=` or `:`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is my problem.  How do I retrieve the metadata from a tif image as a string?  All examples I have seen so far make it to a dict file and that doesn't work here.